# Segue From UIScrollView to Other View In Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, segue

I am doing a image gallery in swift with xcode. The gallery it's like this: (see botton of the post)

I do this With a view called item that has the image view  and the title (xib+ControlView) inserted in a horizontal view, and this view inserted in the scroll view.

I need to do actions with the views when the user touch the image or the title, for example go to other view with all the data of that album.

The question: How is the correct method of doing this? Is there any way for going to other views  from a view that is inserted in a scrollView ? How can i do a segue from story board or from code to other view?(And wich of this 2 method is better)

Thanks for the answers!!

Jo!

[image: My Gallery]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend implementing this as a collection view with one row. Then, you can have a prototype collection view cell in storyboard, and control-drag from this cell to the next view to create your segue.

Comment: Hi!! thanks for answer!!    But, how can i make that the collection view scroll horizontally?   that is posible with that control??

Answer (score 0):

Ad a TapGestureRecognizer on your images Views

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

for add tap gesture is simple to add from storyBoard:

1) open Your storyboard and drag `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your `imageView`

[image]

2) after you see the tap gesture on the header of a view:

[image]

3) right click on gesture and link to your Action in view:

[image]

4) that's it!

Hope this help you

Comment: Hi!! thank you for the answer!!    but how can do to create a seugue from the controls that are inside of the scrollview???  i can't even press the buttons...